# Java/PostgreSQL- CallableStatement.setBoolean null throws NPE

Tags: java, postgresql

I have a PostgreSQL function update_renovation:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION update_renovation(
   p_county character varying, 
   p_municipality character varying, 
   p_district character varying, 
   p_neighbourhood character varying, 
   p_street character varying, 
   p_number character varying, 
   p_reported_by character varying, 
   p_is_renovated boolean) //<-- NOTE THIS boolean

RETURNS void AS
$BODY$
....
```

Now I call this function from java like so

```
CallableStatement statement = con.prepareCall(" { call update_renovation( ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ? ) } ");

        statement.setString(1, request.getAdr().getCounty());
        statement.setString(2, request.getAdr().getMunicipality());
        statement.setString(3, request.getAdr().getDistrict());
        statement.setString(4, request.getAdr().getNeighbourhood());
        statement.setString(5, request.getAdr().getStreet());
        statement.setString(6, request.getAdr().getNumber());
        statement.setString(7, request.getClientID());
        statement.setBoolean(8, request.isRenovated());  //<-- NOTE THIS boolean
        statement.execute();
        statement.close();
```

request.isRenovated() may some times be null (it returns Boolean not boolean).

When this happens java throws NPE on the noted line.

I read the doc on the setBoolean and it accepts boolean (not Boolean) values which may be the cause for the NPE.

Since Postgre accepts NULL values for boolean my question is how do I set it as null on the java server side?

Thanks!

Comment: What does `request.isRenovated()` return? `Boolean` or `boolean`?

Comment: Please read the question- "request.isRenovated() may some times be null (it returns Boolean not boolean)." Still thanks for asking

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `isRenovated()` returns `null`, you should call [`PreparedStatement.setNull()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#setNull-int-int-):

```
if (request.isRenovated() == null) {
    statement.setNull(8, Types.BOOLEAN);
} else {
    statement.setBoolean(8, request.isRenovated());
}
```

Note that you should only have to do this with the `setXXX()` methods that take a primitive argument. You can safely pass a `null` to those that take a reference.